# Setting and stamping time on submit with php

Tags: php

I'm fairly green to PHP and I'm looking for a way to stamp time when a user, submits the form. I only want that time and not the current time. I have tried a few things like print, echo etc. But I can't seem to understand it properly.

Additionally to this my server time is returning a time that is an hour fast. I have tried to combat this with the following but no with no luck.

heres what I have;

```
// The following script only executes when the form is processed.
// set server timezone. declared at the top of my document.
  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London" . '-1');

// set date & time. placed within my isset submit argument.
      $date = date ("l, F jS, Y");
      $time = date ("h:i A");
```

I'm currently calling the these variables with `echo` and `EOD` but, this is always giving me the server time even if the page is refreshed. I'm looking for a stamp of the time.

I'm echoing these variables out within an `EOD` and as a result, the `print`. command is being converted to simple text.

would anyone know of a quick fix to this or am I being a little too green?

Comment: You're aware that London is currently on BST, which is GMT + 1? So if the server time is GMT you'll get the same time.

Comment: Your only looking to display the time stamp once?

Comment: you say "when a user, submits the form. I only want that time and not the current time", why would those times significantly vary?

Comment: @Styphon eh? The server was originally running on `"Europe/Berlin"` timezone. I set it to london thinking the hour was fast... :/ even still increasing the `-1` by one still has no effect on the echoed time.

Comment: @Jeff Puckett II I have a confirmation page that the user can return to with the printed time. if they comback a week later it will only show the time and date of that day. not the day the booking was placed.

Comment: @rackemup420 If possible I would like to place the stamp in a variable and call it in multiple locations.

Comment: You have to store the timestamp somewhere. either in a database or write the info to a file then call it from there. I would suggest saving it in a database with the users id and any other details you would like, then when they come back to the page just pull up all the info for that specific one.

Comment: @rackemup420 that'll be a slight issue as the form is simply sending an email redirecting a user to a landing page, confirming thier booking details. I don't have a database.

Comment: where do you store submitted information?

Comment: @rackemup420 I'm storing the important stuff in cookies and I'm mailing it too. Then again, would a cookie suffice to store the date?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you go through the pain of learning how to set up a database. the business processes revolving around keeping track of booking details inside emails is fraught with problems

Comment: @Jeff Puckett II I do agree with you but as whole im not expecting no more than 50 - 60. if that. My deadline simply doesn't permit the time for such a large task. My given knowledge of databases would also hinder my time constraint.

Comment: then email the customer their booking details as well in a confirmation email. forget about retrieving one later...

Comment: Databases are quite simple to set up. You could even go for SQLITE for faster solutions

Comment: @Jeff Pucket II, I'm already doing so the cookie is more of a fall back.

Comment: Database would be the way to go otherwise I would agree about emailing all the info in the email instead of having a page they can come back to later on. If you had started by working with a database then retrieving/storing info would have been 100% smoother and easier to code around.

Comment: @Phiter Fernandes. If I had it my way I would plug into our current CRM. However my current knowledge would'nt allow this in the time frame I have allotted.

Comment: @rackemup420 My original attempt was to create a page with a DB but I know for a fact I wasn't going to meet my deadline. That being said a discussion with my team has confirmed this is our best route at this time.

Comment: @Jeff Pucket II I'll compromise on the timestamp and loose it on the confirmation webpage. but I will send it in the mail. Can't win em all I guess. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, try just:

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

If that is the timezone you want your script to use.

Then on your server, make sure the server is set to use UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). That is a server set up issue.

https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/setting-the-default-timezone-for-php-to-use

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know.

Comment: You were right, managed to correct the time. :P (For completion sake I'll mark this answer as correct.)